# How to Calculate the Total Tokens Rewarded to a Nominator?

Tags: polkadot-js, rewards, nominator

I'm trying to figure out how to accurately determine the total amount of token rewards received by a nominator in the network. Specifically, I'm interested in the following:

1. **The Total Rewards in Tokens**: I am seeking a method to calculate the total tokens (not reward points) that a nominator has accrued to date for their role in nominating validators. This figure represents the nominator's total payouts from staking activity.
2. **Address-Specific Query**: The solution should allow for querying this information based on a specific nominator's address.

Steps I followed to get this data:

1. Retrieve the eras in which the address has claimed rewards. Below is the code snippet:

   ```typescript
   const data = await api.query.staking.ledger(address);
   const ledger = data.unwrap();
   const claimedRewards = ledger.claimedRewards;
   ```

   [image]
2. Loop through each era to obtain the `totalRewardPoints` received by the address in that
   era, as well as the `totalRewardPoints` for all addresses combined.
3. Fetch the `totalRewardedAmount` in tokens for an era:

   ```typescript
    const totalRewardedAmount = await api.query.staking.erasValidatorReward(
       rewardedEra
     );
   ```
4. I couldn’t find official documentation for the formula to calculate the total rewarded
   amount for a nominator in a specific era, but I obtained this formula from ChatGPT:

   `totalRewardedTokensOfNominatorInAnEra = (nominatorRewardPointsOfTheEra /  totalRewardedPointsOfTheEra) * totalRewardedTokensOfTheEra`

Below is the full code snippet of the `getTotalRewardedAmount` function:

```typescript
const getTotalRewardedAmount = async (address: string) => {
  const api = await getPolkadotApiPromise();

  if (!api) return '';

  try {
    const data = await api.query.staking.ledger(address);
    const ledger = data.unwrapOrDefault();
    const claimedRewards = ledger.claimedRewards;

    const rewardedEras = claimedRewards.map((claimedReward) =>
      claimedReward.toNumber()
    );

    for (const rewardedEra of rewardedEras) {
      const eraReward = await api.query.staking.erasRewardPoints(rewardedEra);
      const individuals = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eraReward.individual));
      let individualRewardPoints = individuals[address] || 0;

      individualRewardPoints = Number(individualRewardPoints);
      const totalRewardedPoints = eraReward.total.toNumber();

      const totalRewardedAmount = await api.query.staking.erasValidatorReward(
        rewardedEra
      );
      
      const totalRewardedTokens = Number(totalRewardedAmount.toString());

      const individualRewardTokens =
        (individualRewardPoints / totalRewardedPoints) * totalRewardedTokens;

      console.log(
        `Total Rewarded Tokens for Nominator: ${individualRewardTokens} for Era: ${rewardedEra}`
      );
    }

    return '';
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return '';
  }
};
```

When using this function, I'm not obtaining the correct values. Also, it appears there’s no straightforward solution to calculate the total rewards (in tokens, not points) earned by a nominator. The calculation involves considering factors like validator commission, total rewards given in an era, etc.

I am seeking guidance on the appropriate API queries to perform for this task. Is there a specific module or function that facilitates this kind of query? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

`pallet-staking` does not store payout information since this will just inflate the storage.
Possible option

- You can also query `Rewarded` events which can give you account and reward details (Given you have an archival node to store previous events)

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L283